# Fastest way to count up to 1 billion in Python

Tags: python, range, python-3.3

Dont have a lot of python/programming experience.
I need to test every number between 1 and 1 billion, then append certain numbers to a list. Currently I'm trying to use range( 0 , Billion ) , but i find that it takes about ~80 secs to do on my machine with Python 3.3. Is there a much more efficient method to do this?

```
for i in range(0, Billion)
    # if i passes test
    i.append(samplelist)
```

Comment: I hope you mean `samplelist.append(i)`.

Comment: `I need to test every number between 1 and 1 billion, then append certain numbers to a list.`, I think you better check your algorithm rather than micro optimizing.

Comment: You might want to think about parallelizing your computation with [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you need to iterate up to 1000000000, there's some better way. For example, you can use some mathematical property to avoid testing every number:

```
samplelist = [x**2 for x in range(int(1000000000**0.5))] # get all perfect squares up to 1000000000
```

Python's not really that fast for numerical operations. So, iterating to 1000000000 and doing something at every single iteration is going to be slow; there's no way around this except to try a faster interpreter (e.g. PyPy), or write the code in a more performant language like C.

---

Alternatively, if you are adding a huge number of elements to a list, then consider using a *generator* instead. This will avoid the overhead of creating a massive list, while still being useful for many things:

```
def gen_numbers(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if <i passes test>:
            yield i

for i in gen_numbers(1000000000):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Sorry but I just noticed this. Using range in the gen_numbers function will anyway create the overhead that we were avoiding in the outer for loop. How will we solve this?

Comment: If you have to iterate through the entire list, this doesn’t save you time. But, for example, if you can process the passing elements as they’re generated, you could be producing results sooner than if you accumulated everything into a list and then processed the list.

Answer (score 3):

No.
Think about the code you have in terms of machine time.  Your test and append functions cannot be touched so all that we have left to play with is for i in range.  This is your basic for loop which is as bare bones as you can get.  You could write a while loop and write another line to increment i yourself, but I suspect that would actually increase your execution time as you are making more calls to the python interpreter that must then be processed.

On second thought, if you could optimize your test routine...

Comment: Well a list comprehension is certainly more efficient than calling append over and over

Comment: @gnibbler: Not by much. Try disassembling a list comprehension.

Comment: Incrementing a counter would at least give you a memory advantage in Python 2.7 but `range()` in Python 3.3 seems more analogous to 2.7's `xrange()`, meaning not all billion values are stored in memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a little faster, but most of the time is probably spent calling `some_test()`

```
samplelist = [i for i in range(1000000000) if some_test(i)]
```

Comment: still not as fast as range. Counting to just a million with my original method took ~.07 sec...with this it took ~0.11 sec, im guessing with a billion the time would add up